# How to use ReactJs in legacy JSF Web application?

Tags: reactjs, jsf

We are planning to migrate the UI of an application from XHTML based legacy JSF (1.X) based framework.

We are not going to change everything at once but would, migrate one of the several tabs in ReactJS and keep rest of the pages as it is in XHTML to see how it goes.

I have been trying to find a way to do this but no luck yet. Can anyone give some hint to go ahead with this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Suggestion: Change everything at once.. Bite the (sour) apple. (or upgrade to a html5 modern jsf 2.2, but even then, do it all at once)

Comment: Did you do it? How was your experience?

Answer (score 1):

my Suggestion:

- -is to split your pages/tabs using any microfrontend approaches       example (iframe, web component )

  - remove any jsf session dependencies and depend on URL query params (keep only one entry point for your splited app)
  - apply sso token ,
  - go ahead with your changes safely without impacting other parts

Answer (score -3):

You would want to prevent coupling between your legacy JSF application and your React components. You could achieve this by making your React-based parts as independent as possible (as with microservices).

- Be wary of state managed in application-/session-scoped beans.
- Don't depend on stuff that you would rather throw away but can't do at the
  moment. Your legacy application is probably too coupled and
  monolithic anyway.
- Keep in mind that you will (should?) throw away your legacy code eventually.
- Keep things clean and fresh for young developers (My experience is, that JSF scares them away - rightly so). This should get yourself a nice and quick developer feedback loop without the need for some heavy build process with legthy container deployments.

Integrate your old and new application using some sort of SSO-like authentication and make your styling seamless.

If you are using [Primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/) as a component library, you can also also benefit from their React components, which are not quite on par with the JSF equivalents, but they give you a starting point to get your look-and-feel right. But then again you establish new, somewhat unobvious coupling with your legacy application. Be careful here.